# Why does lessc encode files as UCS-2 Little Endian?

Tags: css, less, filesize, endianness, ucs2

On a Windows platform with Node running the following command

`lessc style.less > style.css -x --yui-compress`

Outputs a style.css in "UCS-2 Little Endian" format. Normally I wouldn't care, but I noticed my compiled stylsheets had huge file sizes (exactly double, upon inspection). For some reason this encoding doubles the file size when viewed in Windows Explorer.

Converting the files to UTF8 cuts the file size in half. Skipping -x and --yui-compress doesn't affect this.

Any ideas? I care because I don't want to have to work some sort of encoding converter into my build process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try avoiding the > and just specifying the 2 arguments for in and out. When using piping (>) I assume it is the environment deciding the text format.

e.g.

```
lessc -x --yui-compress style.less style.css
```

Comment: Correct! Doing it that way results in ANSI encoding. Thank you

Comment: Windows uses 2-byte characters by default when in "Unicode" mode - other operating systems generally use UTF8.